# Google Cloud does not like my Customer-supplied encryption key (CSEK)

Tags: openssl, google-cloud, base64

I'm trying to encrypt a VM image with my own provided key.

[image]

So I go to my Terminal emulator and do:

```
$ openssl enc -aes256 -A -P                    
enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
Verifying - enter aes-256-cbc encryption password:
salt=DCD571B7A0EC122B
key=786D832EBF415B5F6BCF852AC8DC38826D904DEAFC53885F3B9F49003788B073
iv =B641A744631C462ED2896563F2AB9A1C
```

I punch in the key into Google cloud and it throws back an error:

[image]

So I read the documentation from [Google about CSEK](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption#specifications) and it reads:

[image]

So I run that script, I get the results in base64, but then it doesn't accept it (however, it does accept the one from the Google example).

Do I have to pass this resulting base64 string to `openssl enc`?

I'm a bit lost, and Google doesn't provide any results that apply to my case.

Any help and/or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you've supplied a 64 character HEX value - which does represent 256 bits - however, as it is expecting a base64 string, it looks like a malformed 342 bits

Comment: The key is base64 encoded binary. The key is not base64 encode hex binary.

Comment: Thanks for your input @JaromandaX! How to achieve what Google is expecting?

Comment: use the correct encoding - base64, not hex

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks! But doesn't the -A flag on openssl enc command do that? "-A: Process base64 data on one line (requires -a)"

Comment: first, `requires -a` and second, doesn't do what you think. those values for iv/key are definitely HEX

Comment: maybe something like `echo xxxx... | basenc -d --base16 | basenc --base64` where `xxxx...` is your hex key

Comment: @JaromandaX: Thank you! It's very nice of you to share your knowledge with learners like me, I honestly appreciate this. I will try your recommendation. Thanks again!

Comment: @JaromandaX that worked flawlessly! Thank you, I've learned something new. This is going straight to my notes for future reference!